# Error starting protocol stack: database already contains an incompatible genesis block

Tags: mining

so I am new to Ether, and so I have setup a new node and all seems fine.
now I would like to mine in my own private blockchain so I am running:

```
geth -datadir /home/ethchain/ -dev -unlock 0,1 -mine -rpc -rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 -rpccorsdomain * -rpcport 8101
```

but getting:

```
INFO [09-11|20:45:23] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.6.5-stable-cf87713d/linux-amd64/go1.8.3
INFO [09-11|20:45:23] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ethchain/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: database already contains an incompatible genesis block (have a3c5c170988f516e, new e5be92145a301820)
```

can anyone explain why am I getting this error and how do I execute the mining now?

tx

Sean

Comment: have you defined your genesis.json as in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network

Comment: I ended up just swiching to the testnet, waiting for it to get fully synced so I can continue playing